# How to build a datepicker in Angular with a button (example image)

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, bootstrap-4

So I'm trying to build a datepicker in angular, but i'm not achieving what I pretend.

I use the default angular material datepicker that looks like this:

[image: What I have]

But aesthetically is not what I want to achieve.

Heres an image of what I want:

[image: Objective]

How can i make something like this? All put together?

Thank you in advance.

Best regards!

Comment: Please include a [mcve]. Please also read [*How do I ask a Good Question*](/help/how-to-ask). Make sure that your questions are specific and not overly broad.

Comment: @Igor Just edited the post, hope it looks better. Thank you for your advice.

Comment: If you could use primeNG https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/calendar

Comment: @syed99 I can't use that, only angular material, so I was looking for a css workaround to achieve that

Comment: Your goal looks almost like an input form group from bootstrap with a date icon addon, do you have bootstrap in your project?

Comment: @LeRoi Actually yes, I was trying to implement bootstrap components but It wasnt working until now. But now that you've said that, I tried and it works. I guess I can work with that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The style you want to achieve looks similar to the bootstrap styles.
If you don't have bootstrap in your project it's not too difficult to get the style.

HTML

```
<div class="dp-group">
  <input class="dp-input" [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD">
  <button (click)="picker.open()" class="dp-button">
    <!-- Date Icon Here -->
    ico
  </button>
  <mat-datepicker #picker ></mat-datepicker>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.dp-input {
  padding: .25rem .5rem;
  font-size: .875rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
  background: rgb(238, 238, 238);
  border: 1px solid #d1d1d1;
  border-radius: 3px 0px 0px 3px;
}

.dp-group {
  position: relative;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: stretch;
  width: 100%;
}

.dp-button {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  user-select: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid #d1d1d1;
  border-left: 0px;
  padding: .375rem .75rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px 0px #EEE;
  border-radius: 0px 3px 3px 0px;
}
```

[Check this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ruwsua)

Comment: Thats exacly what i wanted! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

There is more than one appearance for input in Angular Material.

This one can correspond :

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
   <mat-label>Choose a date</mat-label>
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Date">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

[image]

Comment: That could be a solution, since I don't think I'm allowed to use bootstrap components

Answer (score 0):

just beauty

```
  <input  [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date">
  <button (click)="picker.open()">click<button>
  <mat-datepicker #picker ></mat-datepicker>
```